# Is there any easy way to convert multipart/form data to an array in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, forms, sails.js

I am trying some input to get post data as array in Sails/nodeJS;

When I try with this way then get data as array perfectly.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer[1][txt]">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer[1][img]">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer[2][txt]">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer[2][img]">
```

Output:

```
answer:[ { txt: 'ans 1', img: 'yes' }, { txt: 'ans 2', img: 'yes' } ]
```

But when I use enctype(enctype="multipart/form-data") attribute in form then can not get data as previous method.
Output:

```
  'answer[0][txt]': 'ans 1', 'answer[0][img]': 'yes', 
'answer[1][txt]': 'ans 2','answer[1][img]': 'yes',
```

I don't know what happened when I use enctype attribute. I want only first return output data with using enctype(multipart/form-data) attribute.
Thank You

Comment: why do you need to use multipart/form-data?

Comment: for upload images/files

Comment: Are you able to `POST` the `<form>` using `fetch()` , `XMLHttpRequest()` or other function, or can only `html` `<form>` be used?

Comment: just using html form with express js

Comment: You can parse the returned values server side to create an array of objects or `JSON` from the values

Comment: Can not find out the index for 2nd output data and act like string.

Comment: Is the present return value and object or a string? Appears to be an object which you can parse properties, values of to create a new object having properties `txt`, `img`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object from the currently returned object; use `for..in` loop to iterate object, match `"txt"` or `"img"` portion of property, set value to value of existing object

```js
let data = {
  'answer[0][txt]': 'ans 1',
  'answer[0][img]': 'yes',
  'answer[1][txt]': 'ans 2',
  'answer[1][img]': 'yes'
};

let res = {
  answer: []
};

for (let prop in data) {
  res.answer.push({
    [prop.match(/txt|img/)[0]]: data[prop]
  })
}

console.log(res);
```